# Passing Structure from C++ CLI to Unmanaged Code

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, marshalling

I have an unmanaged code that has the following definition,

```
void Load(const somestruct& structinst)
    {
            //dosomething.
    }
```

I want to pass a structure from CLI to this method in the unmanaged code as a ref and get back the structure in CLI.

I tried creating a struct in CLI as

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Sequential, CharSet = CharSet::Ansi, Pack = 2)]
 ref struct TEST
  {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::SysInt)]
      int k;
  };
```

and tried passing the struct as

```
CLIWrapperClass::WrapperMethod()
{
  TEST test;
  this->NativeClassInstance->Load(test);
}
```

and am getting an error like `error C2664: 'NativeClass::Load' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Namespace::WrapperClass::TEST' to 'NativeClass::somestruct&'`

How would I achieve this?

Comment: There are a *lot* of things wrong.  A ref struct is a class in managed code.  You don't use marshaling attributes in C++/CLI, the language is designed to deal with that.  But the real problem is that you just declared a managed type that's different from the unmanaged type.  Compiler doesn't like that.  Write a true wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to touch the `TEST` structure from C#, please make sure that `somestruct` and `TEST` structures have the same members  of the same primitive type with the same size.

If not, why bother with `StructLayout`? Just go and use `somestruct` itself in C++/CLI like:

```
CLIWrapperClass::WrapperMethod()
{
  somestruct test;
  this->NativeClassInstance->Load(test);
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the statement "*`ref struct TEST` is not recognized in C#. It is invalid.*" is wrong. `ref struct` is just a managed reference type that has public (instead of private) members by default; C# sees it absolutely no differently than a managed reference type declared `ref class` -- indeed, they compile to the exact same IL.

Answer (score 0):

native code is incompatible with .net types which can be moved sound by the garbage collector.  it's possible to use pinning and a cast, but that's fragile.  better is just to copy the data from the managed type to an instance of the native struct and back again.